# Adding a delay to inline onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a page which allows you to view items on a google map. You can hover over a business address and it will move the map to that location and open an infowindow.  It works perfectly, but the onmouseover event is inline because every onmouseover has a different id, which is set by a php variable.

The problem is, I need to find a way to add a delay to the onmouseover event, so that the user has to hover over the item for a couple of seconds before the onmouseover is triggered.

I've looked around at some possible solutions, but nothing seems to add the delay.

The onmouseover link looks like this...

```
<a onmouseover="javascript:triggerClick(<?php echo $id; ?>)" href="<?php echo $listingurl; ?>">
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out javascript's `setTimeout()` function. You can use it to cause a delay of specified duration.

Answer (score 2):

You could create something yourself. Split the `onmouseover` event into `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`. This will allow you to start a timeout in the `onmouseenter` event and clear it in the `onmouseleave` event.

```
function onEnter(){
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    //your code
  }, 1000);
}

function onLeave(){
  //in case the user leaves early stop the excution of your code
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

This way you will have a 1 second timeout before your actions triggers and it will not trigger if the user leaves before the time runs out.

**EDIT**

This is the practical use case https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEMpBx

```
<a onmouseover="triggerClick(<?php echo $id; ?>, this)">Foo</a>

function triggerClick(id, element){
  var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    //your code here
  }, 1000);

  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function triggerLeave(event){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    element.removeEventListener('mouseleave', triggerLeave);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sounds good... excuse my ignorance but what would the link look like when I use this?  Baring in mind this part... javascript:triggerClick(<?php echo $id; ?>)   ... needs to remain.

Comment: @user2227359 I've edited the answer giving you a codepen to work with. I think this should fulfill your desire.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made it work thanks to this thread... this is what it looks like now and it works...

```
<a onmouseover="setTimeout(function(){ javascript:triggerClick(<?php echo $id; ?>); }, 1000);" href="<?php echo $listingurl; ?>">
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use this, this will fire multiple times if hovered over it.